# Test Driven Development applied to Database

Tags: java, android, database, unit-testing, tdd

Well i have this code:
https://github.com/ANEDIN/SuperHeroes-Agenda/blob/master/src/com/example/informacion/BaseDatosContactos.java

which is a simple database able to insert, delete and modify Contactos.
I need to make this class using Test Driven Development

i have began this way....

https://github.com/ANEDIN/SuperHeroes-Agenda/blob/master/src/com/example/tests/testBaseDatosContactos.java and function insertarContacto ( addContacto).

Using Eclipse the TestConnection works but testInsertarContacto dont.

Dont know if im beginning the right way an any hint or help would be apreciated.
Also i have doubts if in testBaseDatosContactos i have to clean the database at beginning or end of tests or how to procceed...

Thanks

Comment: Please include the source code in the question directly instead of providing links; if the code is too long, strip it to the necessary parts to understand the problem.

Comment: Its perhaps too long and if i strip it its less readable and clear... if you want i can paste here.. but would be very long in my opinon...

Comment: Well, here's a tip: if your intimate belief is that the problematic code is too long to be pasted into an SO question, then it may very well be that the code is too long, full stop. In any event, include it in the question anyways; some people _do_ take the time to plough through long code samples and harvest from it the necessary elements to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

BasedeDatosContactos.java ( the one I have made, and I need to remake using test driven development)

```
package com.example.informacion;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BaseDatosContactos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /* 
     NOMBRE_BASEDATOS: sera el nombre de nuestro archivo de base de datos
     VERSION_BASEDATOS: la versiÃ³n de nuestra base de datos
     TABLA_CONTACTOS: un string que contiene una sentencia SQL para la creaciÃ³n de una tabla llamada contactos. Lo que tenemos en 
                      parentesis son las columnas, un Ã­ndice INT primario (no es obligatorio pero si muy recomendable para 
                      no tener problemas a la hora de insertar, modificar o borrar alguna fila ya que es un valor Ãºnico) */

private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 4;

// Nombre de nuestro archivo de base de datos
private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "contactos.db";

// Sentencia SQL para la creaciÃ³n de una tabla
private static final String TABLA = "contactos";
private static final String CREAR_TABLA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA 
        + "(nombre TEXT, direccion TEXT, telefono TEXT,email TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,miembrofacebook INT, miembrotwitter INT, miembrogoogle INT, miembrolinkedin INT, sexo INT, tipocontacto TEXT, imagen INT)";

private static final String TAG ="BaseDatosContactos";

/*  La clase ContactoAgenda que quiero almacenar es:
private String Nombre;
private String Direccion;
private String Telefono;
private String mail;

//Cambio boolean por int ya que no va bien en las bases de datos, true=1, false=0
private int miembroFacebook;
private int miembroTwitter;
private int miembroGoogle;
private int miembroLinnkedin;
private int sexo;
private String tipoContacto;
private int drawableImageID; */

public BaseDatosContactos(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA); //db.execSQL(TABLA_CONTACTOS);
    //addContacto(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","1", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, false,"Familia", R.drawable.hulk));
    //Inicializo la base de datos con algun contacto

    insertarContacto(db,"Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","1", "belen@gmail.com",1, 1, 0, 0, 0,"Familia", R.drawable.hulk);
    insertarContacto(db, "Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","2", "daniel@gmail.com",0, 0, 0, 0, 1,"Laboral", R.drawable.spidey);
    insertarContacto(db, "Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","973269128", "eduardo@gmail.com",0, 0, 0, 1, 1,"Amigo", R.drawable.ironman);
    insertarContacto(db,"Asuncion", "c/ Paseo de Ronda","92458", "mama@msn.com",1, 1, 1, 0, 0,"Laboral", R.drawable.thor);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA_CONTACTOS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA);
    onCreate(db);
    //  insertarContacto("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","1", "belen@gmail.com",1, 1, 0, 0, 0,"Familia", R.drawable.hulk);

}
/*
Creamos un mÃ©todo "insertarCONTACTO" y como parÃ¡metros los datos que queremos insertar en la tabla (id, nombre, telefono, email ....). 
Dentro del mÃ©todo creamos una instancia de la clase "SQLiteDatabase" y usamos su mÃ©todo "getWritableDatabase()" para poder 
escribir en la base de datos. Encapsulamos todo en un if por si acaso la base de datos no existe y ya dentro del if creamos 
una instancia de la clase "ContentValues" que como su nombre indica es un almacenador de un conjunto de datos. 
Usamos el metodo "put(key, value)" que nos pide como primer parÃ¡metro "key" el nombre donde establecer el valor almacenado 
y como segundo parÃ¡metro el valor que queremos almacenar. Una vez almacenamos los datos insertamos una fila en la 
tabla usamos el mÃ©todo "insert(table, nullColumnHack, values)" 
*/




public boolean insertarContacto(String nombre, String direccion, String telefono, String email,int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", nombre);
            valores.put("direccion", direccion);
            valores.put("telefono", telefono);
            valores.put("email", email);
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
            valores.put("sexo", sexo);
            valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
            valores.put("imagen", imagen);
            //db.insert("contactos", null, valores);
            try {
                db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores); //TABLA por "contactos"
                return true;
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la insercion: seguramente la clave ya existe.");
            }
        }
        db.close();   
        return false;
    }

    public boolean insertarContacto(SQLiteDatabase db, String nombre, String direccion, String telefono, String email,int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){

        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", nombre);
            valores.put("direccion", direccion);
            valores.put("telefono", telefono);
            valores.put("email", email);
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
            valores.put("sexo", sexo);
            valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
            valores.put("imagen", imagen);
            //db.insert("contactos", null, valores);
            try {
                db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores); //TABLA por "contactos"
                return true;
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la insercion: seguramente la clave ya existe.");
            }
        }   
        return false;
    }

    //Creo un insertarcontacto propio pasandole un contacto
    public boolean insertarContacto(ContactoAgenda contacto){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", contacto.getNombre());
            valores.put("direccion", contacto.getDireccion());
            valores.put("telefono", contacto.getTelefono());
            valores.put("email", contacto.getMail());
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", contacto.isMiembroFacebook());
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", contacto.isMiembroTwitter());
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", contacto.isMiembroGoogle());
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", contacto.isMiembroLinnkedin());
            valores.put("sexo", contacto.isSexo());
            valores.put("tipocontacto", contacto.getTipoContacto());
            valores.put("imagen", contacto.getDrawableImageId());
            //db.insert("contactos", null, valores);

            try {
                db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores); //TABLA por "contactos"
                return true;
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la insercion: seguramente la clave ya existe.");
            }   
        }
        db.close();   
        return false;
    }

    /*El mÃ©todo "update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)" para actualizar/modificar registros de nuestra tabla. 
     * Este mÃ©todo nos pide el nombre de la tabla "table", los valores a modificar/actualizar "values" (ContentValues), 
     * una condiciÃ³n WHERE "whereClause" que nos sirve para indicarle que valor queremos que actualice 
     * (en este caso cogemos como referencia la id de nuestro contacto) y como ultimo parÃ¡metro "whereArgs" podemos pasarle 
     * los valores nuevos a insertar, en este caso no lo vamos a necesitar por lo tanto lo ponemos a null. 
     * Para terminar deberemos cerrar siempre nuestra base de datos con el mÃ©todo "close()".
    */
    public boolean modificarContacto(String nombre, String direccion, String telefono, String email,int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", nombre);
            valores.put("direccion", direccion);
            valores.put("telefono", telefono);
            valores.put("email", email);
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
            valores.put("sexo", sexo);
            valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
            valores.put("imagen", imagen);
            db.update(TABLA, valores, "email=" + email, null);
            //db.update("contactos", valores, "_id=" + id, null);
            db.close();   
            return true;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la modificación.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean modificarContacto(ContactoAgenda contacto){
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", contacto.getNombre());
            valores.put("direccion", contacto.getDireccion());
            valores.put("telefono", contacto.getTelefono());
            valores.put("email", contacto.getMail());
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", contacto.isMiembroFacebook());
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", contacto.isMiembroTwitter());
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", contacto.isMiembroGoogle());
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", contacto.isMiembroLinnkedin());
            valores.put("sexo", contacto.isSexo());
            valores.put("tipocontacto", contacto.getTipoContacto());
            valores.put("imagen", contacto.getDrawableImageId());
            //  String mail="\""+contacto.getMail()+"\"";
            db.update(TABLA, valores, "email=" + contacto.getMail(), null);
            //db.update("contactos", valores, "_id=" + id, null); ---> db.update("contactos", valores, "_id=" + id, null);
            db.close();   
            return true;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la modificación.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
    Para borrar registros usaremos el mÃ©todo "delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs)" que nos pide el nombre de la tabla "table", 
    el registro a borrar "whereClause" que tomaremos como referencia su id y como ultimo parÃ¡metro "whereArgs" los valores a 
    borrar.
    */

    public boolean borrarContacto(String email) 
    {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLA, "email= '" + email+"'", null);
            db.close();  
            return true;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la modificación.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean borrarContacto( ContactoAgenda contacto) 
    {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLA, "email= '" + contacto.getMail()+"'", null);
            db.close();  
            return true;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la modificación.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*Este mÃ©todo devuelve un objeto Contactos con los datos del contacto (id, nombre, telefono, email). En este caso como 
     * queremos leer hacemos uso del mÃ©todo "getReadableDatabase()". Creamos una variable "valores_recuperar" con las columnas 
     * que queremos recuperar, en este caso vamos a recuperar todos los datos de un registro. 
     * Continuamos creando un "Cursor" que se encarga de devolver el resultado de un registro de la tabla y lo almacena en 
     * la memoria, le aplicamos el mÃ©todo: 
     *      query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit)
        Con este mÃ©todo conseguimos leer un registro de la tabla. Como primer parÃ¡metro "table" nos pide el nombre de la tabla, 
        "columns" las columnas que queremos recuperar, con "selection" le indicamos el registro a recuperar (en este caso 
        recuperamos con el id), o los registros a recuperar "selectionArgs", "groupBy" para agrupar los registros consultados, 
        "having" es un filtro para incluir los registros en el cursor (este parÃ¡metro se usarÃ­a con groupBy), "orderBy" para 
         ordenar las filas y "limit" para limitar el numero de filas consultadas.
        Con el mÃ©todo "moveToFirst()" ponemos el cursor al inicio de los datos almacenados. 
        Lo encapsulamos en un if por si acaso no hay datos almacenados.
        Continuamos creando un objeto "Contactos" para almacenar los datos consultados de un registro, y los vamos recuperando 
        del cursor con mÃ©todos get indicando la posiciÃ³n de la columna.
        Para terminar debemos cerrar la base de datos y el cursor.*/

    public ContactoAgenda recuperarContacto(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] valores_recuperar = {"nombre","direccion","telefono","email", "miembrofacebook","miembrotwitter","miembrogoogle","miembrolinkedin","sexo","tipocontacto","imagen"};    

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLA, valores_recuperar, "email= '" + email+"'", null, null, null, null,null);

        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        ContactoAgenda contactos = new ContactoAgenda(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3),c.getInt(4), c.getInt(5), c.getInt(6), c.getInt(7),c.getInt(8), c.getString(9), c.getInt(10));
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return contactos;
    }
```

Then where I'm beginning the test driven... the first thing I want to "port" is insertarContacto...

```
package com.example.tests;

import android.content.Context;

import com.example.informacion.BaseDatosContactos;
import com.example.informacion.BaseDatosGlobal;
import com.example.informacion.ContactoAgenda;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class testBaseDatosContactos extends TestCase {

    private BaseDatosGlobal bdGlobal;
    private BaseDatosContactos bdContactos;
    private ContactoAgenda contacto;

    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        bdGlobal = BaseDatosGlobal.getInstance();
        bdContactos = bdGlobal.agendaBaseDatos;
        contacto = new ContactoAgenda();
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        super.tearDown();
        bdGlobal = null;
        bdContactos = null;
        contacto = null;
    }

    public void testConexion() throws Exception
    {
        assertNotSame(bdGlobal, null);
    }

    public void testInsertarContacto() throws Exception
    {
        contacto.setNombre("Pedro");
        contacto.setDireccion("c/ San Juan 2");
        contacto.setMail("pedro@mail.es");
        contacto.setMiembroFacebook(0);
        contacto.setMiembroGoogle(0);
        contacto.setMiembroLinnkedin(0);
        contacto.setMiembroTwitter(0);
        contacto.setTelefono("999888777");
        contacto.setTipoContacto("Laboral");

        boolean resultado = bdContactos.insertarContacto(contacto);
        assertEquals(resultado, true);
    }
}
```